# Format the String data for its key and value using regex into json key-value pair

Tags: java, json, regex, string

Here is the sammple data which we have to wrap in double quotes "Key":"value" to format :

> {Data:{Management:[{individual:{individual_Suffx:,individual_FName:XYZ,individual_LName:ABC,individual_Emplyee_Title:BOARD SECRETARY&PRESIDENT/CEO,individual_Directng_MName:MNO,individual_DOB:1960-05-21},individual_Tin:{},individual_NPI_Id:{},individual_OrgIndvdl:[{Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_EfctvDt:2009-11-30,Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_RoleCd:W},{Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_EfctvDt:2009-11-30,Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_RoleCd:10},{Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_EfctvDt:2009-11-30,Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_RoleCd:15}],Mngng_Mdcr:{}},{Mngng_Indvdl:{Mngng_Indvdl_FName:TIMOTHY,Mngng_Indvdl_LName:TOOLEY,Mngng_Indvdl_MName:C,Mngng_Indvdl_DOB:1958-07-02},Mngng_Tin:{},Mngng_NPI_Id:{},Mngng_OrgIndvdl:{OwnrshpIntrst_MngngCntrl_EfctvDt:2014-05-01,Ownrshp_MngngCntrl_RoleCd:W},Mngng_Mdcr:{}}}}

Comment: Please clarify what kind of output you want.

Comment: key and value should be wraped in double quotes like json data.

Comment: if you serialize to json there should already be quotes

Comment: You could use jackson to parse it and output it correctly. Does it have to be regex?

Comment: Should all values be in quotes, including integers?

Comment: Yes all values has to be in double quotes. I am having problem because of curly braces. Solution could be anything jackson/regex but it should work. I mean, it should look like json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will cover all corner cases, but this regex should work for your example:

```
String json = ...
json = json.replaceAll("[^{}\\[\\]:,]+", "\"$0\"");
```

Comment: Thanks shmosel, it worked.

Comment: can the solution be modified to skip comma in a whole word. for eg address : line 1, line2 , name : abc.  comma in address should not be considered since its a whole word.

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli not really. Imagine those values in an array: should `[line 1, line2, name]` be parsed as `["line 1", "line2", "name"]` or `["line 1, line2, name"]`? There's no way to know...